# Adding CSS & Target attribute to custom top links in default.xml Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, css, toplinks

I've searched all over google and I found a few tutorials that seems straight forward but I can't get it to work in my `default.xml`.

Majority of the tutorials uses local.xml but I'm not sure where to find that.

Basically, I removed all the top links and added my own. Here is what I have below. This works BUT I need to be able to add a css class and a target of blank.

Any help would be appreciated:

```
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <!-- add ahern access link -->
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="ahern-access-link" htmlClass="ahern-access">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Ahern Access</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">http://ahernaccess.com</argument>
                <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Log In to Ahern Access</argument>
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">ahern-access</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

        <!-- remove existing blocks -->
        <referenceBlock name="header" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />
    </referenceBlock>
```

Or if there is a way to reference a CMS block in `default.xml`?

Comment: Just as a note, the `local.xml` file was used in Magento 1, and has been replaced by the `default.xml` file of each module in Magento 2. In a M1 site, the `local.xml` file was placed in the theme and loaded last in the XML tree so you could do any XML overrides there. In M2 the `default.xml` is loaded on every page on the site and related back to the module based on where it's at in the file structure, but nothing else.

So you can ignore the tutorials for anyone talking about `local.xml` as that wont relate to M2

Comment: Thanks circlesix. I figured as much when I was reading through those tutorials and couldn't find the local.xml. ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="ahern-access-nav">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">{{your css class here}}</argument>
    </arguments>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="ahern-access-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Ahern Access</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">http://ahernaccess.com</argument>
            <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">_blank</argument>
            <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Log In to Ahern Access</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</block>
```

I'm doing some digging in as i have yet to see the target argument used in the wild. If you look at this file **/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Link/Current.php** you will see the list of possible arguments you can make in the comments at the top

```
/**
 * Block representing link with two possible states.
 * "Current" state means link leads to URL equivalent to URL of currently displayed page.
 *
 * @method string                          getLabel()
 * @method string                          getPath()
 * @method string                          getTitle()
 * @method null|array                      getAttributes()
 * @method null|bool                       getCurrent()
 * @method \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current setCurrent(bool $value)
 */
```

Which target is not in. But looking at a few other `default.xml` files, i see things like this in **/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
        <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to Content</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Which relate back to the Template class. So the concept is there, but i'm not 100% on how M2 is implementing that.

For me I have to play around with XML for a while before i land on the exact solution that i need. So i hope this helps.

**Another idea** would be to add the link directly to the template file (i think you are needing **/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml** in this case). It's not an elegent solution, but given that the target="_blank" is not a part of the class, you would have to create a class override to get this functionality in the XML's.

```
<?php case 'other': ?>
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="http://ahernaccess.com" target="_blank">Log In to Ahern Access</a>
    </li>
<?php break; ?>
```

Comment: Okies thanks, I will look into that. 

I also have tried adding the target argument earlier but it didn't work too.

Comment: You might just have to edit the template to get this to work the way you want. I edited my answer to include that option.

Comment: ahhh okies, that's what the Other is. I think that would work just fine as that link will not be touched. thanks so much!

Comment: I just posted the block to give you an idea of what can be done. There are two places in that file you will need to add the link, in the `case: 'welcome'` and the one posted in my answer. if you do that, should be solid. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

As **circlesix** mentioned already, in **/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Link/Current.php** you can see that there is another argument called

```
@method null|array                      getAttributes()
```

So you can use this to insert a target attribute.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="custom-link">
   <arguments>
      <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">YOUR_LABEL</argument>  
      <argument name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="target" xsi:type="string">_blank</item>
      </argument>
      <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">YOUR_PATH</argument>
   </arguments>
</block>
```

Tested in Magento V. 2.1.3

Comment: the "attributes" item is also where you would add the `<argument name="class" xsi:type="string">ahern-access</argument>` that OP also asked about.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the list of allowed attributes here for reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/Html/Link.php

To achieve what you want you need to add the following:

```
<argument name="class" xsi:type="string">your-css-class</argument>
```

Comment: I did try that as well but some reason it wouldn't display the class. I can try again.

Comment: This link is now dead